# errorSummary message for two models

Tags: yii

I want to show errorSummary custom text but for two models.

```
    <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary(array($a,$b)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already supported in Yii. You can pass an array of models to the method, as said [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorSummary-detail).

Comment: Yes, I didn't see that it is a "header" parameter.